# I get an error when I try to change my upload image function name Django

Tags: python, django, backend

Here it is my **models.py** that works.

```py
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from services.utils import unique_slug_generator

from PIL import Image

def upload_location(instance, filename):
    return "%s/%s" %('image/service', filename)
# Create your models here.
class Services(models.Model):
    title  = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    content  = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='all')
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 320 or img.width > 560:
            output_size = (320, 560)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

def slug_generator(sender, instance, *args, **kargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = unique_slug_generator(instance)
pre_save.connect(slug_generator, sender=Services)
```

The problem is when I want to change `def upload_location` 's name.
I tried to use `def upload_location_icon` as name and I changed the **upload_to** to `icon = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location_icon, blank=True, null=True)`

This is the terminal error

[image]

How can I change **def upload_location** name without errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the migration file of your model has a reference to the old name of the function (`upload_location`).

You probably need to run the command `makemigrations` again to have a new migration file.

Or manually modify the existing migration file with the new function name.

Comment: As you can see I tried in terminal to makemigrations but it didnt work. I am looking for a better solution than manually modify the existing migration.

Comment: @DragosNeata I would suggest you manually modify the migrations file to change the function name, I don't know of any other solution.

Comment: Can I delete the migrations and do it somehow clean? Cause I am not sure how to manually modify it.

Comment: @DragosNeata just go to the migration file, change `upload_location` to `upload_location_icon` and commit the new changes (if it was already commited). That should be it, nothing else required.

Comment: After some more work on my code I came back and tried to run the command `makemigrations` agian. Guess what. It worked and I dont understand how.... But thank you :))